# Deriving the equations for a moving inertial reference frame

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

I assume $c=1$ in the following derivation:

In order to derive the equations for a moving inertial reference frame, I immediately wrote down the following:

$$ x'=Ax+Bt, \tag{1}$$

$$t'= Dx+Et. \tag{2}$$

In order to solve it I would need 4 independent equations. Here they are:

1. Since the speed of light is constant in all reference frames, it follows that if $x = t$, also $x' = t'$, therefore

$$At+Bt=(Dt+Et) \overset{(x=t)}{\implies} A+B=D+E. \tag{3}$$

2. I can reverse the reference frame and the physics should be the same hence 
   $$x=0 \implies x'=-vt' \implies B=-Ev. \tag{4}$$
3. Finding the $x'$ component of the point $A(\frac{1}{1-v},\frac{v}{1-v})$ gives:

   $$Av+B= -Av. \tag{5}$$
4. Finally finding the $t'$ component of $A$ gives (I'll do this one explicitly):

   $$t'= \frac{D+Ev}{1-v}. \tag{6}$$

   From the diagram one can read off using the Pythagorean theorem that:

$$t'= \sqrt{\left( \frac{1}{1-v} \right)^2 +\left( \frac{v}{1-v} \right)^2 } = \frac{\sqrt{1+v^2}}{1-v}$$
  $$\implies D+Ev= \sqrt{1+v^2}. \tag{7}$$

[image]

From these equations one easily arrives at the desired result ie
$$x'=\frac{x-vt}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \; \text{and} \; t'=\frac{t-vx}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \tag{8}$$

All this seems to be correct. However considering the equation $(6)$ and putting back the $c$'s in it one arrives at the equation

$$ D+Ev= \sqrt{1+v^2} \quad (!) \tag{9}$$

First of all this dimensionally doesn't make sense. Secondly if you calculate and find the coefficients you don't get the correct answer. Intuitively I know that this equation has to be $D+Ev= \sqrt{1+v^2/c^2}$ so that everything works perfectly but I don't know why this has to be so and I cannot show it by reasoning physically. I fell in my guts that there is something fishy about using Pythagorean theorem but I don't know what went wrong exactly. If I just say that the use of Pythagorean is wrong, then I cannot explain why it gives the correct answer when using $c=1$. Such a coincidence seems to be highly unlikely.

**Edit**: I've made a major typo in the diagram you should swap $x=0$ with $t=0$ and $x'=0$ with $t'=0$!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [check-my-work questions are off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) and the correct version of this derivation can [easily be found elsewhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#Galilean_and_Einstein.27s_relativity).

Comment: I haven't seen this derivation before. In $A(\frac{1}{1-v},\frac{v}{1-v}$, which is the x and which is the t? They almost seem to be plugged in inconsistently. Also keep in mind B and D are not dimensionless quantities.

Comment: @MonkeysUncle The first coordinate is $x$ and the second is $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You work too hard and the idea of setting $c=1$ may make problems.
I copy here the equations that you obtained and that I found correct. So,
1. The speed of light is the same in each frame implies

$$Act + Bt = c(Dct + Et), \overset{(x=t)}{\implies} Ac + B = Dc^2 + Ec. \tag{i}$$

2. Reversing the frames gives indeed

$$B = -Ev. \tag{ii}$$

3. Also in the frame $(x,t)$ the origin $x'=0$ of the frame $(x',t')$ moves at velocity $v$

$$B = -Av. \tag {iii}$$

Notice also that from $\text {(ii)}$ and $\text {(iii)}$ one infers

$$E = A, \tag{iv}$$

and introducing all these relations in $\text {(i)}$,

$$Ac - Av = Dc^2 + Ac \overset{(x=t)}{\implies} D = -\frac {Av}{c^2} \tag{v}$$.

4. Now putting all these things together I rewrite your transformations $(1)$ and $(2)$

$$x' = A(x - vt), \ \ \ ct' = A(-\frac {vx}{c} + ct). \tag{vi}$$

Whatever remains is to find A. In this task, the interval conservation is bound to help,

$$c^2t'^2 - x'^2 = c^2t^2 - x^2. \tag {vii}$$

So let's do the calculus,

$$A^2 \left[(-\frac {vx}{c} + ct)^2 - (x - vt)^2 \right] = c^2t^2 - x^2. $$

Doing the calculus you get

$$A = \frac {1}{\sqrt {1 - \frac {v^2}{c^2}}} \tag{viii}$$

So let's now rewrite the transformations

$$x' = \frac {x - vt}{\sqrt {1 - \frac {v^2}{c^2}}}, \ \ \ ct' = \frac {ct -\frac {vx}{c}}{\sqrt {1 - \frac {v^2}{c^2}}}. \tag{ix}$$

Now, I saw that you have a problem with the calculus of your expression $(6)$ but you didn't say what it means. Anyway, for $D$ see my formula $\text {(v)}$ and for $E$ my formula $\text {(iv)}$. You can rely on them, they are obtained in a simple way.

Comment: @Sofia I've retracted my downvote, because your answer has changed completely :)

Comment: @Sofia  Eqn 6 comes from plugging in the values of point A into the eqn 2.

Comment: @Sofia you have used the fact that the proper time is conserved in all reference frames but we don't know that yet. How can you know if a particular measure is conserved under a transformation without knowing the transformation?

Comment: @Sofia I've written my comment way before you've changed your answer so now I deleted the comment. I'm sorry if you have to experience a bad night (or a morning I don't know) because of that :)

Comment: @Sofia I didn't notice that I was using the same letter for two distinct things. The **point** A is the intersection of $x=vt$ aka $t'=0$ and $x=t+1$ ie the **point** A gives in the moving reference frame the arrival time of the first light beam. You can see the point A in the diagram I've put in my question. It is located ca. $A(0.8|1.8)$

Comment: @gonenc please tell me: up to which point in my proof do you agree? Up to the point 4, i.e. including eqs. (vi) I didn't use the conservation of the relativistic interval. Now, I prefer to work with $c \ne 1$, otherwise I don't feel sure. I will try to see what happens with this point, but, may I call it P?

Comment: @Sofia I agree until you say *interval conservation is bound to help*. Because you cannot know if that particular expression for an interval is conserved if you don't know what the transformation is. BTW of course you can call it P :)

Comment: @gonenc very well, so let me see what's going. By the wy, I have different other duties meanwhile, s.t. if you write me and I don't answer immediately, don't worry.

Comment: @gonenc   are you sure that $t' = 0$ implies $x = vt$? Please look at my eqs. (vi). They are clean, as I said, until them (inclusively) I didn't use the rel. interval conservation. So, what I get from them is that $t' = 0 \overset{(x=t)}{\implies} t = (vx)/c^2$. Therefore, 1st of all tell me if you agree with me, and then we'll continue.

Comment: @Sofia No $t'=0$ does not imply $x=vt$! I am utterly sorry for the fatal typo that I've made in my diagram. However the calculations are correct. I've redone them again on a piece of paper! I agree with you until the eqn vi (vi inclusive). BTW Should we move these comments to the chat? PhySe asks me to do so insistently.

Comment: Yes, we should move to chat, because soon we well get protests. But you can do smth. else (I hope) - delete all your comments until now. Can you? About *fatal*, nothing is fatal, nobody died. It's O.K. and don't worry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21962/discussion-between-gonenc-and-sofia).

Comment: @gonenc Just let me tell you my result: at the intersection of the lines $t = vx/c^2$ and $x = c(t + 1)$ I get $t = (v/c)/(1 - v/c)$.

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry, but I have no time to find your mistake for you. However, I can give you a tip that I am 100% sure would work.

Your mistake can be very easily found by dimensional analysis. Start from the beginning of your derivation and check all formulas. The first one which makes no sense due to dimensions is wrong.

You can just say that because $c$ is one in your calculations, you define $v$ do be what is actually $v/c$. That would give correct results by simple substitution $v \rightarrow v / c$, but I am under impression that is not good enough for you, though I can't understand why.

Comment: That doesn't help at all. I've already indicated in my answer that putting in $c$'s back creates a dimensional problem. Besides when $c=1$, velocities are dimensionless so it makes sense dimensionally. Furthermore even the first equation is dimensionally sensible because I didn't tell you what dimensions $A,B,D$ and $E$ are.

Comment: @gonenc, dimensions of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are induced by dimensions you use for lengths and time intervals, so they are different when $c=1$ and $c\neq 1$. My suggestion was to find the first formula which is incompatible with this redefinition of dimensions, which is the mistake.